# Adding rows in CSV files in python

Tags: python, csv

```
def sumRows(filename, header=False):
d = {}
total = 0
with open ('{0}'.format(filename)) as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in rdr:
        if(header==True):
            rdr.next() 
            # skips first row if header is set to true
            continue
            total = ? 
            # function I do not know how to do
            d[row[0]] = total
print(d)
```

Example of the CSV file:

```
bob    15   4   4
tim    29       0
anna   18       9
```

I need it to add the rows like, for bob it should be 15+4+4, tim it should be 29+0 and it should ignore any blanks, does anyone have any idea how I could do this in python 3? It should print in the form of a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pandas, you can do it simply as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None).set_index(0)
print(df.sum(axis = 1))
```

P.S. `read_csv` reads csv with default ',' as separator. To can change the separator using `sep` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the text cells into a number, ignoring the blank cells, and then `sum` them.

```
def sum_rows(filename, header=False):
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        if header:
            rdr.next()
        for row in rdr:
            d[row[0]] = sum(int(s) for s in row[1:] if s.strip() != '')
    return d
```

By the way you should also move the code that deals with the header to before the loop; otherwise, it will run this on every iteration of the loop.